# No puedo ejecutar un proyecto en NEXT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

no puedo ejecutar un proyecto desarrollado en NEXT JS. me sale el siquiente mensaje.

restaurant@ dev C:\Users\BGH\Desktop\youtube-next-food-ordering-app

> next dev

"next" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! restaurant@ dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the restaurant@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BGH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-15T01_54_10_653Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\BGH\Desktop\youtube-next-food-ordering-app>

Comment: Ejecutaste `npm install` antes de intentar correr el comando para el entorno de desarrollo?

Comment: Si te sale ese error, solo ejecuta npm install --force, para mi caso eso solucionó el problema

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema y ejecuto en modo desarrollo con el siguiente comando, el número es el puerto donde la app se ejecutará.

```
npx next dev -p 3000
```